The energy test and distance
In the Székely-Rizzo article (Székely and Rizzo: A new test for multivariate normality, 2005) it is stated:

Suppose that $X,Y$ are real-valued independent random variables with
cumulative distribution function $F$ and $G$, respectively. It is easy
to show that if $X’$ is an independent and identically distributed
(iid) copy of $X$, and $Y’$ is an iid copy of $Y$, then:
$$2 \int_{-\infty}^{\infty}(F(x)-G(x))^2 dx = 2 \mathbb{E} (|X-Y|) -
> \mathbb{E} (|X-X'|) - \mathbb{E} (|Y-Y'|)$$

Can you help me with the most detailed explanation possible on how this equation holds?
Thanks!

Could you prove a bit more explanation, to understand what you question is about?

Yeah, I did, thanks for the clarificating question!
